# Powershell - Multidimensional array issues

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I've got some fun issues with a multidimensional array that just aren't making sense to me. I'm sure I'm just misusing something or expecting functionality that isn't quite there with PS. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$Packages = @()

$Packages += @("program 1","c:\path\to\program.exe","/switch")
$Packages += @("program 2","c:\path\to\program2.exe","/switch")

foreach ($Package in $Packages) {
    $Name, $Path, $Args = $Package
    Install-Program $Name $Path $Args
}
```

Install-Program is a function I've written that checks the package filetype (currently works with .msp, .msu, .msi, and .exe) and just has it install as silently as I can manage it (obviously not all .exe installers have a silent switch, grumble grumble).

The issue seems to be that when I iterate through the $Packages array, the $Package entry it pulls is from every element in each row of the array, i.e., it returns

`$Package=$Packages[0][0]` then `$Package=$Packages[0][1]` etc.,

instead of

`$Package=$Packages[0]` then `$Package=$Packages[1]` etc.

What's the least complicated way to make it do the latter?

Comment: Prepend the array literals with a unary array operator (`,`), like so: `$Packages += ,@('...','...')`

Comment: ... I feel both annoyed and very silly that I missed this. Thank you VERY much. I need to look into this strange operator. :))

Comment: Happy to help :-) `about_Operators` should be mandatory reading for anyone getting into [tag:powershell] btw